# Pandas read file from azure blob storage wasbs path

Tags: pandas, azure-blob-storage

I want to read the file from Azure blob storage(using wasbs) to Pandas data frame. I am able to read using Spark. However I need to do using Pandas.

**Ex:** 'wasbs://test_container@storagetest.blob.core.windows.net/files/abc.csv'

Answer (score -1):

you can use

`pandas_df = spark_df.toPandas()`

or if you are using databricks: 
you can read mounted azure storage using FUSE. You can access wasb like local file system by using the path `/dbfs/mnt/<yourMountLocation>/files/abc.csv`